# Export RCP with plug-in project as dependency failure

Tags: export, eclipse-rcp

I had a **RCP** application that uses a **plug-in project** as dependency. I have added the plug-in project into `MANIFEST.MF` of my RCP program and it works well. But when I exported the program, it posted an error:

[image]

The `build.properties` is as follows:

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               Application.e4xmi,\
               plugin.xml,\
               com.hpi.hpdm.console.dependencies;bundle-version="1.0.0"
source.. = src/
source.. = src/
jars.compile.order = .
source.com.hpi.hpdm.console.dependencies;bundle-version="1.0.0"/ =
```

Comment: `com.hpi.hpdm.console.dependencies` is the plug-in project, `com.hpi.hpdm.console` is the main project.

I don't know what `"\com.hpi.hpdm.console\"1.0.0"\=" does not exise!` means. Any clues will be appreciated.

***Updated:***

The `build.properties`:
[image]

The `.product` file `Contents` tab:
[image]

Comment: How are you building the RCP? Are you using a xxxx.product file?

Comment: Yes, it can successfully started but can not be exported. I don't know how to include the dependencies into the executable app.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but I need to know how you are doing the export because there is clearly a problem in that. I repeat, are you using a .product file?

Comment: Yes, i use the .product file.

Answer (score 1):

When exporting an RCP your `.product` file must list every plugin (or feature) that is used by the RCP.

If you are using a feature based product configuration:

Open the feature.xml for your code and add all your plugins to the feature (in your case the feature is 'com.hpi.hpdm.console.feature').

If you are using a plugin based product configuration:

Open the .product file editor and switch to the 'Contents' tab. If your main plugin is listed there you should be able to use the 'Add Required' button to update the list. Make sure that all your plugins have been included (along with a lot of standard Eclipse plugins).

Comment: It seems not to work, why I can't find my plugin project at the Feature Selection page. Is the configuration right? Please refer to my updated screenshots. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are using a feature based product build rather than plugin based. You must update your feature to include all your plugins - updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I update my feature and the build.properties, it works.